# How to determine when SQL Server Express is not enough

Tags: performance, sql-server, sql, windows-server-2016

My web server is using SQL Server Express edition with multiple databases serving multiple websites and perhaps 100 simultaneous users at any given moment.

Memory usage seems to always be near 1 GB (the limit for Express edition).

Despite hitting the limit, web pages are responsive and the database queries seem fast enough.

How do I determine whether I should upgrade to SQL Server Web Edition?

What signs will appear that performance is affected?  Will the queries time out?  Will the queries slow down?